# How to extract vector of exact coordinates of the image in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to write the code for the model of GAN generator using keras with tensorflow backend. I want the generator output to be vector (for each image in the batch the same size) of values of the image in exact coordinates. These coordinates are given as an input do the generator also.

I've tried using `tf.gather_nd` as a function to do numpy-like operation of extracting values from exact coordinates.

`img` is a generated from the noise image with shape=(?,28,28,1),

`coordinates` is an input tensor of the shape (?,80,2) with 80 points to be extracted from the generated image `img`,

`vect` is an output vector, should be the size of (?, 80),
where ? is a batch size.

```
vect = Lambda(lambda x: tf.gather_nd(x, tf.cast(coordinates, 'int64')))(img)
```

Finally the output shape of this function is (?,80,28,1) instead of (?,80).

How is it better to extract such points?

Comment: So from this output vector, with size `(?, 80)`, you want to make an image putting those 80 values in the coordinates given by `coordinates`, right? I think you need [`tf.scatter_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_nd). What is the shape of the output image, is it also `(?, 28, 28, 1)`? And the image points for which there are no values, should they just be zero?

Comment: No, I just want to extract values from the image in exact coordinates. So the output is just a vector of size `(?,80)`, where `?` is a batch size

Comment: Ah okay so you want to obtain the `(?,80)` vectors, sorry I thought that was the input you had. You're right, you need [`tf.gather_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd), I'll fix my answer.

Comment: Updated my answer, hopefully actually addressing your problem now.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with [`tf.gather_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd) like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def extract_pixels(img, coords):
    # Number of images and pixels
    s = tf.shape(coords, out_type=coords.dtype)
    n = s[0]
    p = s[1]
    # Make gather index
    i = tf.range(n)
    ii = tf.tile(i[:, tf.newaxis, tf.newaxis], [1, p, 1])
    idx = tf.concat([ii, coords], axis=-1)
    # Gather pixel values
    pixels = tf.gather_nd(tf.squeeze(img, axis=-1), idx)
    return pixels

# ...
vect = Lambda(lambda x: extract_pixels(x, tf.cast(coordinates, 'int64')))(img)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In a toy example this works, but when I try to compile it in the model, there is an error in the function `tf.tile`: `TypeError: List of Tensors when single Tensor expected`. I think that the problem could be in the variable `p`, as this is a tensor with length `()`..

Comment: @Alexandra Which tensor has shape `()`? Maybe you can do `print(img)` and `print(coords)` to see what are the shapes of the tensors right before the error is triggered?

Comment: `n` and `p` variables have these shapes. The shape of `s` is `(3,)`. If I print `coords.get_shape()` its values are `(?, 80, 2)`, for the image `(?, 28,28,1)`.